# what do i do if i can not remove zune from my desktop on my Windows phone

Tags: zune

When I'm in certain apps like when I'm trying to download wallpaper when I go to save the wallpaper a message will pop up saying I cant save the image I have to remove Zune from my desktop first and IV tried the stop the music apps they are not working either.

Comment: Please clarify which phone you have as well as what version of Windows Phone it's running.

Comment: What exactly does the message say?

Answer (score 1):

Zune Music and Groove Music are the same in Windows 10 desktop. So try running

`remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.ZuneMusic_3.6.12711.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`

in a command line prompt or Power shell with admin rights.